# Why golang append same slice result will share one memory address?

Tags: go, append

I thought `append` in go, will return a new result, but I find that append in same slice will return same memory address:

```
func TestRuneAppend3(t *testing.T) {
    r := make([][]rune, 256)
    r[0] = append(r[0], 99)  // c
    r[1] = append(r[0], 100) // d
    r[2] = append(r[0], 101) // e
    // I thought it would be "c cd ce", but it is "c ce ce"
    log.Println(string(r[0]), string(r[1]), string(r[2]))
}
```

So what is the best way if I want to the result is `c cd ce`?

Answer (score 3):

Append will only allocate a new array if there isn't sufficient capacity in the slice you're appending to. If you need to have a separate array, use `make` to create a new slice and use `copy` to copy whatever you need from the original slice.

[This article](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) gives a good explanation of how slices work.